# Fiware Wstore Billing

Tags: fiware

How can I configure Wstore to print in the billing which also generates the calculation of taxes? Since, I passed the address of the tax but does not calculate the percentage.

[image: img]

Answer (score 1):

The current version of WStore does not deal with taxes. Additionally, this GE is in support mode, which means that no new features will be developed. Nevertheless, the provided functionality has not been deprecated in FIWARE, but a new GE which integrates the FIWARE Business Framework is going to be released in September.

My advice if you want to use the FIWARE business framework is waiting until September, when the new Business API Ecosystem GE will be released. This GE has been built using the components of the business framework (WStore, RSS) in a single component, which simplifies its use. Additionally, it has been updated to expose a set of standard APIs defined by the TM Forum.

Comment: Thankyou for you answare. I try to modify wstore code for calcolate tax and insert fiscal code in billing, can you suggest me the files to modify? In which directory i watch? In your opinion ,  is possibile mode code send adddress state and fiscal code or tax code ? Under Italian law , is' mandatory Thankyou very match